# Generate an Obj-C Method

Tags: objective-c, code-generation

Is it possible to generate an Obj-C method? - For example:

```
- (void)doSomething:(BOOL)isLater
{
    if (isLater == FALSE)
    {
        NSLog(@"Not Later");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Is Later");
    }
}
```

I'm specifically talking about generating the logic, I have some code that can create a class and add an existing method, but I'd like to know If I can generate the logic for the method itself and add it to a method?

```
static NSString *Description(id self, SEL _cmd)
{
    return @"My Description Method";
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    Class mySubclass = objc_allocateClassPair([NSObject class], "MySubclass", 0);

    // grab NSObject's description signature so we can borrow it
    Method description = class_getInstanceMethod([NSObject class],
                                             @selector(description));
    const char *types = method_getTypeEncoding(description);

    // now add
    class_addMethod(mySubclass, @selector(description), (IMP)Description, types);

    objc_registerClassPair(mySubclass);

    id myInstance = [[mySubclass alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", myInstance);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we are splitting hair:

## Yes, technically, you can.

**But it won't be easy at all.**

Objective-C can be parsed by [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html) (the C++ library which the `clang` compiler is based on) and then JIT-compiled and run using [LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/group__LLVMCCore.html).

This way, you can embed clang and LLVM into your program, generate some Objective-C source text dynamically, parse it into an abstract syntax tree (or generate that AST directly, without writing and parsing any Objective-C), and compiling it. If you write a method that does this, then you can essentially run arbitrary Objective-C code dynamically from within your application.